# Metro bundler react native dynamic component loading

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack

I am creating a stack using **react** and **react-native** and i am planning to share the container(logic) code, alongside i am also creating dumb UIcomponents(functions that return the layout) for both native and web .

I was trying to conditionally import the UIcomponents for different builds . I was able to do that with web using **webpack's NormalModuleReplacementPlugin** but i couldn't find a way to do the same with the **metro bundler** as there is no documentation available .

**So is there a way to actually configure your setup in such a way that you can conditionally import components for react-native using metro bundler** . The import statement in es6 only uses string literals and though you can club variables with require in react , it doesn't work with react-native .

Right now everytime i run the command it triggers a script which reads the file and changes the import statements from 
`../native/One.component` 
to 
`../web/One.component` and vice versa for native to web

But this way i won't be able to shoot both the servers for debugging . I want to know is there a cleaner way to do that ?

Comment: I'm also trying to solve a problem that I believe hinges on configuring metro-bundler, but I am not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: Yes , actually the main issue is that there is no official documentation for metro bundler and not many configuration option , i looked into the code of the library and couldn't find anything that could solve the problem . I was planning to bootstrap the application using webpack so i had a better control of the application but i failed . So for now I am using a script which changes the import statements . I am not able to debug both web and mobile and that same time but atleast its automated

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/bundling according to this documentation, dynamic imports are not supported

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your terminal and type this:

1. `sudo lsof -i :8081`
2. `kill -9 <PID>`